# Xamarin forms with Microsoft Band IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, microsoft-band

Im using sample from Microsoft Band Sdk with Xamarin forms.
It works on Universal app, but fails in Xamarin from a MAC(Macincloud) deployed to iphone. Downloaded the Xamarin Band nuget package and it finds my band, but wont connect.

```
      IEnumerable<BandDeviceInfo> pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetPairedBandsAsync();
            if (pairedBands.Count() < 1)
            {
                return;
            }
BandDeviceInfo curBand = pairedBands.FirstOrDefault();
 // Connect to Microsoft Band.
//Code stops here on iphone, waiting forever.
     bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(curBand);
```

Any tips would be appreciated :)